# WPF TextBox Caret Disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, caret

I'm developing a WPF application that has `TextBox` components.

I'm having a problem with the caret of the text boxes. It seems that, depending on the location of the `TextBox` itself, the caret disappears on certain specific locations

Caret showing:

[image: Caret showing]

Caret disappears:

[image: Caret disappears]

Caret returns:

[image]

The `TextBox` style is very simple:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="FormTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="464"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="74"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="43.2"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="50"/>
</Style>
```

I tried even setting the font to `Courier New` which is monospace font, same thing.

Comment: Do you have any event handler on text change? Can't reproduce this on a simple wpf app

Comment: No, But on the window containing the `UserControl` I have this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19579704/975959 in order to support multi resolution

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be common ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567910/wpf-scale-to-textbox-textbox-can-not-display-cursor-when-i-click-textbox), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551351/wpf-scale-to-textbox-textbox-can-not-display-cursor-when-i-click-textbox)) with the scale transformation, which is being applied by the behavior you mentioned in comments.

```
mainElement.LayoutTransform = scaleTransform;
```

And from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aeaa3e28-a7da-4208-9676-771231c1a954/textbox-caret-not-visible-when-scaled-down-in-net-40?forum=wpf), there's no

> effective solution for this issue.

So, if you want to support multi-resolution, I would recommend [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox); simple, and do the job.

Comment: Thanks,
I tried replacing the Behavior with the ViewBox, but it didn't solve the Caret issue, Still sometimes missing.